# Beautiful dance of the Earth and Venus around the sun

Tags: graphics, programming, graphics3d, astronomy

I have seen very nice dynamic graphics created by users of Ma. I would like to get help whether the following graphics can be created using Ma. I was not able to create the dynamic picture here. Therefore, I have the link here for original graphics: [link to original graphics](https://www.facebook.com/brightside/videos/893000730828671/) [image: Beautiful Dance of the Earth and Venus around the Sum]

Comment: Ooooh, yeah, the one where they pretend that 365.25/224.7=13/8 because it's prettier, and, you know, who cares ;-). (Which is to say: the nice, closed structure is only approximately there, as good a job as that video does at pretending it's exact. As long as you keep that in mind, then yeah, it's quite pretty.)

Comment: @Emilio, that's why I went for the curated data instead of the idealized model, where it can be seen that the tracks are manifestly not epicycloids. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did some [time ago](https://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/hidden-beauty/).

```
tv = 225;
te = 365.25;
rv = 0.72;
re = 1;
e[t_] := {Cos[2 Pi t/te], Sin[2 Pi t/te]};
v[t_] := 0.72 {Cos[2 Pi t/tv], Sin[2 Pi t/tv]};
vis[t_, s_] := Graphics[
  {Yellow, PointSize[0.05], Point[{0, 0}], White, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
   Circle[{0, 0}, 0.72], Blue, PointSize[0.03],
   Point[v[t]], Red, Point[e[t]],
   White,
   Table[Line[{v[j], e[j]}], {j, 0, t, s}]}, Background -> Black]
```

Visualizing the cosmic dance:

```
tbl = Table[vis[t, Pi], {t, 0, 1000 Pi, 5 Pi}];
```

This was exported as a gif (this is a down sampled version).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ubpdqn for taking time to answer this question . I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ramesh thank you. I learned a lot from all the answers. I just happened to have a 'canned answer'. :)

Answer (score 15):

Here's something that is nowhere near the sophistication of the original, but might get you started.

The following assumes an orbital period for Venus of 225 days (thanks Michael!), and an average orbital distance from the sun of 0.72 AU (from very superficial Google searches).

```
Table[
  Module[
   {venus, earth},
   venus = 0.72 AngleVector[2 Pi/225 d];
   earth = AngleVector[2 Pi/365 d];
   {
    Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.1],
    Opacity[0.2], Gray, Through[{Point, Line}[{earth, venus}]]
   }
  ],
  {d, 1, 10 365, 4}
] // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You will have to play with the step and duration of your simulation to obtain different effects.

Comment: Venus's orbital period is 225 days, not 295 days.  (And its rotation period is 245 days, but that's another story.)

Comment: @Michael, oops you are right! I can't even copy numbers from Google anymore :-) Fixed!

Comment: @Michael and Marco: `UnitConvert[PlanetData["Venus", "OrbitPeriod"], "Days"]` ;)

Comment: @J.M. Yep, I should have done that, but for my visceral aversion to the way access to curated data and units are currently implemented...

Comment: Can't argue with that. :)

Comment: Thank you Marco for taking time to answer this question . I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 15):

Might as well...

```
eorb = PlanetData["Earth", "OrbitPath"];
vorb = PlanetData["Venus", "OrbitPath"];

dl = DateRange[{2010, 1, 1}, {2015, 12, 31}, "Week"];

epos = Table[QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
             PlanetData["Earth", EntityProperty["Planet",
                                                "HelioCoordinates", {"Date" -> dates}]], 
                                           "AstronomicalUnit"]], {dates, dl}];

vpos = Table[QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
             PlanetData["Venus", EntityProperty["Planet",
                                                "HelioCoordinates", {"Date" -> dates}]], 
                                           "AstronomicalUnit"]], {dates, dl}];

Graphics[{{Orange, vorb}, {LightBlue, eorb},
          {Directive[Opacity[2/3, White]], MapThread[Line[{##}] &, {epos, vpos}]}} /.
          v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ] :> Most[v], Background -> Black]
```

[image: that ain't an epicycloid]

(N.B. See the revision history for a version that uses `AstronomicalData[]`. For some reason (all the associated gymnastics with `Entity[]`, perhaps), that was faster than using `PlanetData[]`)

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tvxwY.png) is what you get if you go back further in time.

Comment: Thank you J. M.  for taking time to answer this question . I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 9):

With the caveat that it has zero physical meaning whatsoever, here you go:

```
\[Omega]v = 365.25/225;
rv = 0.72;
lines = Table[Line[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, rv {Cos[\[Omega]v t], Sin[\[Omega]v t]}}], {t, 0, 20 \[Pi], \[Pi]/40}];
Graphics[{White, Opacity[0.4], lines, Opacity[1], Red, Circle[], Circle[{0, 0}, rv]}, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

And if you want an animation, the following code should do the trick:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{White, Opacity[0.4], Take[lines, i], Opacity[1], Red,  Circle[], Circle[{0, 0}, rv]}, Background -> Black], {i, 1, Length[lines], 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for taking time to answer this question . I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

See for a start [Cardioid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cardioid.html) or [Cardioid, Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid). If i'm not mistaken this stuff is called *Line Art, String Art and Curve Stitching*.

(Code Intellectual property of Matt Henderson of http://blog.matthen.com)

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Table[Line[{{Sin[a], Cos[a]}, {Sin[a + 2 Pi/3 + t], 
Cos[a + 2 Pi/3]}}], {a, 0, 2 Pi - 0.001, Pi/50}]}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

so you can work with:

```
rVenus = a/(1 + e*Cos[\[Theta]]) /. {a -> 0.723, e -> 0.0068, i -> 3.3947}
rEarth = a/(1 + e*Cos[\[Theta]]) /. {a -> 1, e -> 0.0167, i -> 0}
```

$\frac{0.723}{0.0068 \cos (\theta )+1}$

$\frac{1}{0.0167 \cos (\theta )+1}$

```
rv = 0.723

wv = 365.24/225.1

Graphics[Table[Line[{{Cos[rVenus], Sin[rVenus]}, rv {Cos[wv rVenus], Sin[wv 
rVenus]}}], {rVenus, 0, 10 \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Louis for taking time to answer this question . I really appreciate it.